# Necessity of "the fact that"

Tags: grammaticality

Which of the following would be correct? Are there any other ways to say the same thing?

- Are they okay with me having asked this question?
- Are they okay with my having asked this question?
- Are they okay that I asked this question?
- Are they okay with that I asked this question?
- Are they okay with the fact that I asked this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer is:

> *Are they okay with the fact that I asked this question?*.

All the others are grammatically incorrect except number 1.  However, it has a different meaning.

The one you want means:

Are **they** okay with the **fact** that **you have asked a question.**

Number 1 has a different meaning:

Are **they** okay with ***you*** **after** you asked the question.

Comment: The second is grammatically correct. And the first one doesn't mean that: "me having asked this question" is, as a whole, the object of "okay with".

Comment: Actually, it can mean either.  I'm not mentioning your version since I already have.